# Passing a storage pointer to a struct as an argument

Tags: solidity

What kind of solidity functions can one pass a storage pointer to a struct as an argument? Say between public and private functions or internal and external functions?

Comment: What do you mean "pass a pointer to a struct"??? There is no such thing as "passing something to a struct" in any programming language which I can possibly think of.

Comment: You can pass a storage pointer to an internal function or instantiate an instance of a struct or array as a storage pointer. Think of the pointers as a cost-effective alternative to copying the data (usually larger).

Comment: @goodvibration presumably he means that the pointer points to the storage address of a struct, not that the pointer is an argument to the struct

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, I'll go with Tjaden's interpretation of the question.

This *might* help with understanding storage pointers: https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089

You can pass them around internally.

By "type", I think you mean *visibility*, so `internal` and `private`, not `public` or `external`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Pointer {

    struct MyStruct {
        address a;
        bool b;
        uint u;
    }
    mapping(bytes32 => MyStruct) public myStructs;

    event LogActivity(address sender, address a, bool b, uint u);

    function emitter(MyStruct storage s) internal {
        emit LogActivity(msg.sender, s.a, s.b, s.u);
    }

    function callMe(bytes32 key) public {
        emitter(myStructs[key]);
    }

    function setter(bytes32 key, address a, bool b, uint u) public {
        MyStruct storage s = myStructs[key];
        s.a = a;
        s.b = b;
        s.u = u;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.